# Transformation of Dependent and Independent Variables

Tags: data-transformation, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I have a few Independent variables that's normal and a Dependent variables that's skewed , I pick **log(feature+SHIFT)** to correct skewness. The procedure I follow to get prediction is just take **exp(predictions)-SHIFT**.

Now how do I get my predictions for the following cases.

1) I have Normal - dependent variable and the independent variables are skewed , I transform only a **few of them** using same **log(feature+SHIFT)** where the shifts are unique for every feature.

2) Transformations on both dependent and independent variables with different **SHIFT values**.

Suitable code examples will be highly appreciated. Thanks